# 2 switch Button for Sound and Music Corona SDK?

Tags: button, audio, lua, widget, coronasdk

I need help regarding my  widget switch button. I've created 2 switch button which is for sound switch and music switch but the problem is every time i switch off and switch on the music switch the music(mp3 sound) is being unresponsive means its speed is fastforwarding every time i switch music on/off. Next problem is Everytime i switch off sound switch it also switch off the music(mp3 sound).
Heres my code:

--utils.lua

```
local sounds = {}
sounds["select"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/select.mp3")
sounds["score"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/score.mp3")
sounds["incorrect"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/gameover.mp3")
sounds["clap"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/clapping.mp3")
sounds["music"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/gameMusic.mp3")

M.playSound = function(name) 
    if sounds[name] ~= nil then 
        audio.play(sounds[name])
    end
end
```

--Settings.lua

```
soundSwitchPressed = function(event)
local switch = event.target
utils.playSound("select")


if switch.id == "sound" then 
    if switch.isOn == true then 
        audio.setVolume(0)
    else
        audio.setVolume(1)
    end
end
end

musicSwitchPressed = function(event)
    local switch = event.target
    utils.playSound("music")

    if switch.id == "music" then 
        if switch.isOn == true then 
            audio.setVolume(0)
        else
            audio.setVolume(1)
        end

    end
end



local sound_switch = widget.newSwitch
    {  
        left = _W-70,
        top = navBar.y + navBar.height/2 + 44,
        style = "onOff",
        id = "sound",
        x = 800,
        y = 960,   
        onPress = soundSwitchPressed
    }
    sound_switch.xScale, sound_switch.yScale = 3, 3
    uiGroup:insert(sound_switch)

    local music_switch = widget.newSwitch
    {  
        left = _W-70,
        top = navBar.y + navBar.height/2 + 44,
        style = "onOff",
        id = "music",
        x = 800,
        y = 1200,   
        onPress = musicSwitchPressed
    }

    if audio.getVolume() == 0 then 
        sound_switch:setState({isOn=false, isAnimated=false})
        music_switch:setState({isOn=false, isAnimated=false})
    else
        sound_switch:setState({isOn=true, isAnimated=false})
        music_switch:setState({isOn=true, isAnimated=false})
    end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your way is good. I'm beginer but I want help you:)

From Corona documentation about [`audio.setVolume()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/setVolume.html)

> Sets the volume either for a specific channel, or sets the master
>   volume.

So `audio.setVolume()` affects all sounds and music.

Maybe try use variable to determine whether play or not sounds and music.

utils.lua

```
audio.reserveChannels( 6 )
...
sounds["select"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/select.mp3")
sounds["score"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/score.mp3")
sounds["incorrect"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/gameover.mp3")
sounds["clap"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/clapping.mp3")
sounds["music"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/gameMusic.mp3")

local channels = {}
sounds["select"] = 1
sounds["score"] = 2
sounds["incorrect"] = 3
sounds["clap"] = 4
sounds["music"] = 5

music = audio.loadStream( "backgroundMusic.mp3" ) 

M.soundOn = true
M.musicOn = true

M.playMusic = function() 
    if music ~= nil then 
        audio.play( music, { channel = 6 })
    end
end

M.playSound = function(name) 
        if sounds[name] ~= nil then 
            audio.play(sounds[name], { channel = channels[name]})
        end
    end
```

Settings.lua

```
...
soundSwitchPressed = function(event)
local switch = event.target

if utils.soundOn then
    utils.playSound("select")
end

if switch.id == "sound" then 
    if switch.isOn == true then 
        utils.soundOn = true
    else
        utils.soundOn = false
        audio.stop(1)
        audio.stop(2)
        audio.stop(3)
        audio.stop(4)  
        audio.stop(5) 
    end
end
end
...

musicSwitchPressed = function(event)
    local switch = event.target

    if utils.musicOn then
        utils.playSound("music")
    end

    if switch.id == "music" then 
        if switch.isOn == true then 
            utils.musicOn = true
            utils.playMusic()
        else
            utils.musicOn = false
            audio.stop(6)
        end

    end
end
```

Whenever you play sound put code

```
if utils.soundOn then
    utils.playSound("your_sound_effect_name")
end
```

or

```
if utils.musicOn then
    utils.playMusic()
end
```

Read more about [audio](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html).

Comment: Mr. Idurniat is there another way to declare the channel? ex. sounds["select"].channel = 1 <-- im having an error with this kind of declaration it said ERROR: attempt to index field 'select' (a user data value).. btw i tried this sounds["clap"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/clapping.mp3",{channel =1}) still has the same error...ill read more about audios...

Comment: I have improve my answer. It should work now. It is incorrect syntax `sounds["clap"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/clapping.mp3",{channel =1})` You need  use `channel` parameter when you play, stop, etc. for example `audio.stop(1)` or `audio.setVolume(0, {channel = 1})` .

Comment: You are really a great help idurniat but how will i able to save the animated of my switch button?After clicking backbutton my switch wont save itself.  My if-else statement audio.getVolume is not saving my animated switch button after you edit the codes. But i tried if audio.stop() == nil. still doesn't work.

Comment: Try save state of newSwitch between scene. Read more about it [here](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/43839-widgetnewswitch/)

Comment: idurniat audio.stop doesnt work on loadstream and loadsound so i made the solution that you can set the volume on a specific variable. I change the audio.stop(1-6) to audio.setVolume( 0.0, { sounds[name] } )  and from the playSound function i change it to audio.play(sounds[name]). Thank you for your guide..